# Why does pd.df.rolling.aggregate takes so much longer when the input is a list?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-rolling

I'm using python 3.8.3 and pandas 1.1.5.

`table_in.T` is a 18 by 209997 pandas dataframe. `window` and `periods` are both set to 12.

The following three lines of code respectively takes 9.52s, 6.27s and 5min53s to run.

```
rolledsum2_in = table_in.T.rolling(window, min_periods=periods).agg('sum')
rolledmean2_in = table_in.T.rolling(window, min_periods=periods).agg('mean')
rolledsumean_in = table_in.T.rolling(window, min_periods=periods).agg(['sum','mean'])
```

Why does it take so much longer when aggregating the rolling object by sum and mean together than doing them separately?

Comment: This is likely pretty dependent on the underlying data, you can use the `prun` and `memit` modules to see "under the hood" and check what portions of the code are using the most processor and memory